# Accessing Apache page using NGINX after custom authentication

Tags: nginx

I am using ubuntu 14.04, In which apache is running on port :8080 and Nginx is running on port :80

I am using following code to access apache pages using nginx with my own login page for authentication rather than default login page:

```
server {
        listen 80;
#       listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

 location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        #proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=";
        error_page  405     =200 $uri;
        }
}
```

And my login page is  index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Apache using nginx</h1>
      <form method="post" action="index.html">
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username" required></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" required></p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>

    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

And i have set password into : /etc/nginx/.htpasswd

My problem is when i am access the page it open index.php it is correct

it i am entering correct or incorrect password everytime it is displaying same page saying:

405 Not Allowed
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

WIth wrong credential it is ok but when i am giving right credential it should allow me to access my page.

Please help me

Comment: I have installed the Nginx auth_request module and now able to get username and password what i have set into "proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" in the variables $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"]  & $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_PW"].

Comment: If anyone want to access the page directly, it should shows "401 Authorization Required" in nginx. But if authenticated user access the same page it must need to open the requested page . I want to handle it on the nginx server. Is it possible, if yes then what would be the steps.

I will be very thankful to you if you give your precious time to identify my problem.